# Open nonempty subset of irreducible variety over $k$ has the same Krull dimension as the whole variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $V$ be an irreducible variety of finite type over a field $k$, $V_{0}\subseteq V$ open and nonempty (or at least dense). Why is \begin{equation*}\operatorname{dim}_{\operatorname{Krull}}(V_{0})=\operatorname{dim}_{\operatorname{Krull}}(V)\text{?}\end{equation*}

My professor uses this result (without mentioning a proof) as if it were somehow self-evident. I have tried to prove it, but I am at a loss. Who can help?

The general statement is NOT true for arbitrary irreducible topological spaces, not even for varieties of finite type over an arbitrary integral domain, see 
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078775/krull-dimension-of-dense-open-subset-of-finite-type-algebra-over-a-domain) for instance.

Comment: You can find the answer in "Algebraic Geometry", of Robin Hartshorne.

Comment: 1. Your title question does not match your body question - please resolve this. 2. What have you tried?

Comment: @Somerandommathematician can you be more specific, where exactly? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg and therefore "dense" is a weaker condition than "open and nonempty", hence the parenthetical remark makes sense.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Krull dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]/\left&lt; x_1x_3-x_2^2,x_2 x_4-x_3^2,x_1x_4-x_2 x_3\right&gt;$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167321/krull-dimension-of-mathbbcx-1-x-2-x-3-x-4-left-x-1x-3-x-22-x-2-x-4-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that the dimension of an irreducible variety is equal to the transcendence degree of its function field (over the base field $k$).  Since $V_0$ is dense in $V$, it has the same function field.

Comment: Actually we have this statements for integral schemes. How can you drop the reduced property?

Comment: The statement is not true for arbitrary integral schemes.  In any case reducedness is irrelevant since the statement is true for a scheme $X$ iff it is true for $X_red$.

Comment: The statement you wrote is Proposition 2.5.19 of Liu's book for integral varieties. So it is correct. The problem is that you do not use integral but irreducible. How can you define the function field of an irreducible variety? Moreover, can you elaborate why your second sentence is true? I would like to understand why I can prove a property for Xred instead.

Comment: It is not true for arbitrary integral schemes.  It is true for integral schemes of finite type over a field, which I guess is what you mean by "integral varieties".  $X$ is homeomorphic to $X_{red}$ and the statement only involves the topology.

Comment: In any case "integral" and "irreducible" are equivalent for varieties, at least if you define varieties to be reduced (which most people do).

Comment: Liu does not do it.